# make get_post work in the loop

Tags: loop, get-post

I'm getting a post by id with get_post();

```
$post = get_post(17);
$page = get_post_meta(17);
setup_postdata( $post ); 
include($page['_wp_page_template'][0]);
```

After getting the post I include a pagetemplate wich contains a:

```
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
```

If I call `the_title()` from outside the loop I get the right title of the post called with get_post().
If I call `the_title()` from within the loop I get the title of the current page I'm on. How do I get the data from the `get_post` into the loop.

Comment: Why are you loading a page template inside another page template?

Comment: I'm creating a one page website, and want to give the admin the possibility to give the parts of the page an different layout.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `setup_postdata( $post )` you need to use the global `$post` as for some reason it does not work without that specific variable. Once you manually set `$post` to a new value, you are altering the `$post` global, so you will need to reset it back to the current post of the main query.

Apart from that, you should never use any global variables set by Wordpress as a custom variable as this can cause non debuggable issues and unexpected results from your code. Breaking a global variable and then trying to debug such an issue will drive you up a mountain ;-)

In your specific use case, you need to add `wp_reset_postdata()` immediately after your custom query is done

```
$post = get_post(17);
$page_template = get_post_meta(17);
setup_postdata( $post ); 
include($page_template['_wp_page_template'][0]);
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to handle these things and your question is a little light on detail *why* you need.

Specific to the title part — to retrieve title of specific post you shouldn't be messing with globals at all, just do `$title = get_the_title( 17 );` or around that.

In *most* of the cases template tags have a version that retrieves data for *specific* post, not just *current* post in the loop. There is also a lower level `get_post_field()` to retrieve raw or nearly raw data for the post.